# Show that the infimum is convex

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let f be  bounded convex function on a convex subset $A\times B \in \mathbb{R^m}\times\mathbb{R^n}$. Define $g(x)=\inf{f(x,y):y\in B}$ Show that g is convex on $A$.

Okay, let $x = (x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2), x_1,y_1 \in A, x_2,y_2 \in B$.

Since $A\times B$ is convex, for all $x,y \in A\times B, \lambda \in[0,1],\: \lambda y+(1-\lambda)x \in A\times B$

So since f is convex on $A\times B,\lambda f(y)+(1-\lambda)f(x)\le \lambda f(y)+(1-\lambda)f(x)$

But $\lambda f(y)+(1-\lambda)f(x) \ge \lambda \inf(f(y))+(1-\lambda)\inf(f(x))\ge \inf(f(\lambda f(y)+(1-\lambda)f(x))$ so it is convex.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your notations are really confusing and the end of the proof is incorrect (or it does not help the proof). You can prove it as follows.
$$ g(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda) x_2) \leq f( \lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda) x_2,\lambda y_1 + (1 - \lambda)y_2) $$
for any $y_1,y_2 \in B$. Thus, by convexity of $f$,
$$ g(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda) x_2)  \leq \lambda f(x_1,y_1) + (1 - \lambda) f(x_2,y_2).  $$
Since this holds for all $y_1,y_2$, it holds for the infima.

Comment: "Since this holds for all y1,y2, it holds for the infima." This would be obvious for minima, but not really for the infima.

Comment: That implication is alright, since it is not a strict inequality.